# Как создать блок с выпадающим текстом, при открытии которого блок будет принимать другую форму

Tags: javascript, html, css

Суть в чем. Нужно сделать блок с выпадающим текстом. Но не простой. Обычно он имеет форму скруглённого прямоугольника, в центре которого текст, назовём заголовок, а при открытии, нужно чтобы он (блок) менял форму под количество текста которое будет раскрыто. Как то так [image: Выезжающий текст]

Пробовал реализовать, получилось так себе [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
<div class="info">
    <input id="info__body_1" class="info__switch" type="checkbox">
    <label for="info__body_1" class="info__headline">Выезжающий текст</label>
    <div class="info__body">
        Очень много текста, который будет появляться при выезжании, а так же фон, стрелка и бордер будут менять цвет. 
    </div>
</div>
```

```
.info:hover, .info:focus, .info:active{
    border: 1px solid rgba(211, 0, 50, 0.5);
    /*box-shadow: 22px 22px 128px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    border-radius: 18px;*/
    background: #FFE3E3;
}
.info {
    position: relative;
    width: 1360px;
    height: 100px;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    background: #FFFFFF;
    border: 1px solid #F2F2F2;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border-radius: 18px;
}
  .info__switch {
    display: none;
}
.info__body {
    max-height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    transition: 0.4s;
    width: 1209px;
    height: 81px;
    left: 76px;
    top: 56.5px;

    font-family: Euclid Circular A;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 500;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 28px;
    /* or 175% */


    color: #5B5B5D;
}
.info__switch:checked~.info__body {
    max-height: 100px;
}
.info__headline::before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    left: 1195px;
    top: 12.5px;
    border: 6px solid #39739d;
    border-bottom-color: transparent;
    border-right-color: transparent;
    border-left-color: transparent;
}
.info__switch:checked~.info__headline::before {
    transform: rotate(180deg) translateY(6px);
}
.info__headline {
    position: relative;
    width: 521px;
    height: 25px;
    left: 76px;
    top: 38px;

    font-family: Euclid Circular A;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 20px;
    line-height: 25px;

    color: #191919;
}
.info__headline:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ... при открытии, нужно чтобы он (блок) менял форму под количество текста...

Почему форму то менять? Размеры же! Даже квадрат это частный случай прямоугольника.

Так как в метках вопроса указаны только **html** и **css**, то вариантов немного, и у всех один и тот же недостаток - сложно добиться нужной плавности раскрытия/закрытия.

```css
.info {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  border: 2px solid #d4ced1;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius: .833em;
  overflow: hidden;
  font: bold 14px/1em "Euclid Circular A", sans-serif;
  background-color: #fff9f9;
}
.info:focus-within { border: 2px solid rgba(211, 0, 50, 0.5); }
.info:hover, .info:active { border-style: dotted; }

.info__switch { position: absolute; width: 0px; }

.info__headline {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 1.666em;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-align: center;
  transition: 0.4s ease-out;
}
.info__switch:checked~.info__headline {
  background-color: #ffe4e4;
  transition: 0.4s ease-in;
}

.info__headline::after {
  content: "";
  height: .666em; width: .666em;
  border-bottom: .166em solid #101010;
  border-right: .166em solid #101010;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-50%, -0%);
  transition: 0.4s ease-in-out;
}
.info__switch:checked~.info__headline::after {
  transform: translate(-50%, -0%) rotate(45deg) scale(-1);
}

.info__body {
  position: relative;
  max-height: 0;
  padding: 0 2.366em 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  overflow: hidden;
  flex: 1;
  font-size: .7em;
  font-weight: normal;
  color: #5b5b5d;
  transition: 0.6s cubic-bezier(.24, .29, .4, .99);
}
.info__switch:checked~.info__body {
  max-height: 100vh;
  padding: 0 2.366em 2.366em;
  background-color: #ffe4e4;
  transition: 0.4s ease-in;
}

.info__body::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0; left: 0;
  height: 2.366em; width: 100%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(#0000, #ffe4e4);
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox">
<div class="info">
  <input class="info__switch" id="info__body_1" type="checkbox">
  <label class="info__headline" for="info__body_1">Выезжающий текст</label>
  <div class="info__body">Суть в чем. Нужно сделать блок с выпадающим текстом. Но не простой. Обычно он имеет форму скруглённого прямоугольника, в центре которого текст, назовём заголовок, а при открытии, нужно чтобы он (блок) менял форму под количество текста которое будет
    раскрыто. Очень много текста, который будет появляться при выезжании, а так же фон, стрелка и бордер будут менять цвет.Суть в чем. Нужно сделать блок с выпадающим текстом. Но не простой. Обычно он имеет форму скруглённого прямоугольника, в центре
    которого текст, назовём заголовок, а при открытии, нужно чтобы он (блок) менял форму под количество текста которое будет раскрыто. Очень много текста, который будет появляться при выезжании, а так же фон, стрелка и бордер будут менять цвет.Суть в
    чем. Нужно сделать блок с выпадающим текстом. Но не простой. Обычно он имеет форму скруглённого прямоугольника, в центре которого текст, назовём заголовок, а при открытии, нужно чтобы он (блок) менял форму под количество текста которое будет раскрыто.
    Очень много текста, который будет появляться при выезжании, а так же фон, стрелка и бордер будут менять цвет.Суть в чем. Нужно сделать блок с выпадающим текстом. Но не простой. Обычно он имеет форму скруглённого прямоугольника, в центре которого текст,
    назовём заголовок, а при открытии, нужно чтобы он (блок) менял форму под количество текста которое будет раскрыто. Очень много текста, который будет появляться при выезжании, а так же фон, стрелка и бордер будут менять цвет.
  </div>
</div>
<input type="checkbox">
```

Чтобы избавиться от этого недостатка, нужно уже использовать скрипты, для предварительного вычисления высоты раскрытого блока.

*Дополнительные `<input>`-ы только для проверки фокусировки через клавишу <kbd>Tab</kbd>.*

Comment: Метки html и css указал потому, что не знал, что можно и как реализовать с помощью js.

Answer (score 0):

Довольно простое и примитивное решение с использованием JS, думаю если вам надо будет подправить какие-то стили то вы с этим и сами справитесь

```js
(() => {
  var block = document.querySelector(".main__block");
  block.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    var slideBlock = document.querySelector(".main__block--down");
    var arrow = document.querySelector(".arrow");

    if (!slideBlock.classList.contains('open')) {
      slideBlock.classList.add('open');
      arrow.innerHTML = "⬆";
    } else {
      slideBlock.classList.remove('open');
      arrow.innerHTML = "⬇";
    }
  });
})();
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.main__block:hover, .main__block:focus, .main__block:active{
    border: 1px solid rgba(211, 0, 50, 0.5);
    /*box-shadow: 22px 22px 128px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    border-radius: 18px;*/
    background: #FFE3E3;
}

.main__block--down {
  margin-top: 20px;
  display: none;
}

.open {
  display: block;
}

.main__block {
  background-color: #fff9f9;
  padding: 25px;
  width: 70%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 1px solid rgba(211, 0, 50, 0.5);
  border-radius: 18px;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.main__block--text {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

.main__block--text p {
  font-family: Euclid Circular A, sans-serif;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 16px;
}
```

```html
    <div class="main__block">
      <div class="main__block--text">
        <p>Выезжающий текст</p>
        <p class="arrow">⬇</p>
      </div>
      <div class="main__block--down">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nihil quidem laboriosam architecto, rem vero facilis facere aliquid accusamus neque! Eum, similique harum molestias fugit consectetur ullam reiciendis tempora officia tempore velit, alias unde asperiores quos optio quisquam eius? Maxime, quidem atque libero aliquam exercitationem hic aut. Impedit, quo sequi eligendi, delectus commodi, odit minus nostrum itaque earum cupiditate animi possimus aperiam eveniet aliquam sint enim maiores odio! Dolores, quod? Minus atque dolorum distinctio, at est velit doloremque commodi deserunt suscipit alias nihil nisi fugiat quo eveniet eius? Quia iusto at omnis sed quis ducimus fuga soluta cumque fugit facere libero non maiores consectetur amet, quas pariatur quidem hic exercitationem quam odio suscipit dolorum, modi delectus natus. Ullam deserunt eveniet itaque.
      </div>
    </div>
```